# How can I change the css of this when I click on anything but this?

Tags: jquery, css, click

I am attempting to change the css of menu items by clicking anywhere else on the screen. This is to reset they're css properties after already clicking on them and changing the css from they're defaults.

If I have a list item with `id="linkitem"` how to I click on anything but `#linkitem` to change the css of it.

Thanks

Comment: Just to note, you shouldn't have the same id on two different elements.  It isn't valid HTML.  I suggest using a class of `linkitem` instead.  You reference classes with `.classname` instead of `#idname`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).on('click', function(e) {
    if ( ! $(e.target).closest('#linkitem').length ) {
        // you clicked anywhere but on an element inside #linkitem (or itself)
        $('#linkitem').css('color', 'red');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, could you break down the second line so i can undrstand it better?

Comment: @crm - clicking the document, means the click function fires when clicking anywhere. e.target would be the actual element that was clicked, and using closest() we check if the element that was actually clicked either has that ID, or has a parent with that ID, which would mean the clicked element is inside the #linkitem element, and if the clicked element is not inside the #linkitem, and the clicked is not #linkitem itself, you clicked somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('li').not('#linkitem').click(function(){
    //change css here
});
```

[And the fiddle illustrating this behavior](http://jsfiddle.net/kUQ9g/)

[And the documentation for jQuery.not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/)

Answer (score 1):

You need a negative selector

```
$(':not(#linkitem)').click(function(){
    //insert code here
});
```

Comment: jQuery's psuedo selectors cannot leverage the performance boost provided by `querySelectorAll()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('body').on('click', function(e) {
    if(e.target.id === 'linkitem'){
       // Do something
    }
    else {
       // something else
    }
});
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be: if( e.target.id === 'linkitem' ){...} ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean but you can simply do:

```
$(":not(#linkitem)").on('click',function(){
    alert("I was callled");
}
```